# Access ViewNavigatorApplication's actionbar component from View

Tags: android, apache-flex, flex4

I want to change icon of button thats in actioncontent of ViewNavigatorApplication from a view.

ViewNavigatorApplication loads views which are mxml components. i tried

```
Object(navigator.activeView).refreshbutton.icon = "../assets/r.gif";
```

It throws runtime error saying it couldn't find element.

Comment: Am amazed no one has solution to this. I googled and tried everything possible but no solution :(

Comment: In addition to my answer, since your app runs locally, you should consider embedding the icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your button is called **refreshbutton** and your app is called **MyApp**

```
MyApp(FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication).refreshbutton.icon="../assets/r.gif";
```

It's important to understand that your casting the top level application as your own app so it knows about the contents of your main level app including actionContent.

This isn't a very good development practice in general. I prefer to use a MVC pattern but that would be a very long answer.

Comment: I got error and found i didnt import library for FlexGlobals, so do import fleglobals library. 

`import mx.core.FlexGlobals;`

Comment: Also can you help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206197/flex-4-data-service-init-and-result-overload